# PHP - Clipping a directory of images together

Tags: php, image

Let's say I have a directory of images that is 32 pixels (32x32) and I want to make it a sprite-sheet. I don't want to do it manually cause it will take too long but how do I make it so every single image gets smashed into one image that is one line... so.. 32px height by width would be much larger (obviously).

Thanks

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php (i.e. there are better ways to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ImageMagick, as Crontab suggested. It's the right tool for the job. You can have your PHP script execute a shell script; in that shell script, you can use the right ImageMagick commands.

Comment: I don't know how to use ImageMagick :\

Comment: Follow the link that Crontab provided and learn. It's a relatively simple command line utility on both Windows and Linux. It's the industry standard for image manipulations.

Comment: I got `montage -background #336699 -geometry +0+0 t0.png t1.png all_tiles.png` so far but I don't wanna type it all out...

Answer (score 1):

Although ImageMagick is the way to go, you do not need to call a shell script.

Instead use the [ImageMagick PHP class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). This is part of the PECL archive and so is easily installed even on most hosted web servers.